# Permission and Access & Edit Item

Tags: permissions

i created 2 Groups "Site Owners" ( with Approve & Contribute Permission) and "Site Member" (only Contribute Permission ) and i have 3 account (Administrator, Useradmin ,UserMember ).
"Site Owners" has Administrator, Useradmin while "Site Member" has only UserMember but Owner of "Site Member" is Useradmin instead of Administrator.
i changed Read & Edit access to "Only their own" in List Advanced Settings also i configured "Permissions for this List".

When UserMember Creates new item , Useradmin can not see any Item but administrator can see it.
**Why ?** Isn't Useradmin is Owner of Site Member ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the your list view shows only those items that was created by the currently logged in user. So if your useradmin has not created any items , he wont see any in the list. In the list advance settings you actually need to make it read all it items instead of limiting them to the creator.

Create a public view , that will have the filter in created by column with the value `[me]`

And a create a personal view for the list owners and administrators that includes all items in the list.  In this approach you will not only ensure that members are only able see to items that were created by them but also that admins are able to view all items in the list.